# Parcelable OR Serializable : Which is better option to communicate between two activities?

Tags: java, android

I have bunch of data like Model classes, Array list & some other data type based on requirements.

Now, I am planning to start flexible & light weight way to communicate with activities & fragments with heavy data which should not be affect to UI.

Comment: Parcel has more performance than Serializable. You can learn more about them here https://android.jlelse.eu/parcelable-vs-serializable-6a2556d51538

Answer (score 1):

Parcelable is better because in Serializable java reflection is used which is a slow process. Serializable creates a lot of temporary objects and thus creates a lot of garbage collectable variables. Whereas in Parcelabe we will be defining explicitly the variables and methods, this takes up a bit of time but it is worth it.